# Couchdb View does not re-index

Tags: couchdb

I have a view which looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type === 'article' && (Date.parse(doc.published) < (Date.now() - 30 * 60 * 1000))) {
        emit(doc._id, doc._rev);
    }
}
```

The view basically emits articles that are stale (i.e. {{published date}} < {{present - 30 minutes}}.

Now, the issue is as follows:  The view does not update itself after the first read. The first access builds the view on all documents as expected. But thereafter it seems like it only updates itself on change (delete, create or update of new documents).

This is however an issue and not what I desire. ***I have other articles that are getting stale as time progresses*** therefore I would like couch to return these articles too but since they are not changed they don't come up in the view.

This, what I just described, seems to be expected couchdb behavior (?). But, is there a way to show aging artciles too ?

PS: An easy way to test this is to insert a document with published=Date.now() and type="article" and run this view. After 30 minutes you will see the document is actually stale as per the view definition but it will not show up in the view. 
30 minutes is just a number. You can reduce it to a smaller time frame if you want. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I can confirm, that this is expected behaviour of couchdb views. Views will only be recalculated when changed (for the new documents). Idea: Try to have the `doc.published` a part of your key, like `emit([Date.parse(doc.published), doc._id], doc._rev);` so you can create a query selecting everything older than x seconds.

Comment: @JuliusBeckmann Thank you for your suggestion. Do you mean that I check if the articles is stale in the application logic (using start/end key) and not in the view itself ? ...

Comment: Think of a view as a generated index. This index will not change by itself, but you can change the query to have a traversion of that index. So yes, use a query using start/end on that view to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is by design. The view index is only updated on the Create Update and Delete parts of CRUD operations.

Filtering by something dynamic during a Read is done with a key.

In your case you would probably want to emit as follows:

```
emit(doc.published, doc);
```

Then in your call to CouchDB you would add parameters that would further filter on the published date.